# Discord.py wait for message or reaction

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm quite new to both Python and Discord.py, and I'm trying to find how to make the bot wait for either a message or reaction from user at the same time.

I tried separating each but just resulted in the bot needing a message response before a reaction.

Here's a similar code I'm trying to do:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return

    if ctx.content == "$respond":
        message = await ctx.send("Waiting for response...")

        while True:
            try:
                response = #Will wait for a message(Yes or No) or reaction(Check or Cross) from ctx.author for 30 secs
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.edit(content=f"{ctx.author} did not respond anymore!")
                break

            if response.content == "yes":
                await message.edit(content=f"{ctx.author} said yes!")
                continue
            
            elif response.content == "no":
                await message.edit(content=f"{ctx.author} said nyo!")
                continue
            
            #These are reactions
            elif str(response.emoji) == "✅":
                await message.edit(content=f"ctx.author reacted ✅!")
                continue
            
            elif str(response.emoji) == "❌":
                await messave.edit(content=f"Stopped listening to responses.")
                break
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) is what you're looking for here.

I would recommend using `bot.command()` for command handling purposes but this is fine as well.

This is how you wait for specific events (provided as the first argument) with specific conditions (as provided in the `check` param)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == bot.user:
        # if the author is the bot itself we just return to prevent recursive behaviour
        return
    if msg.content == "$response":

        sent_message = await msg.channel.send("Waiting for response...")
        res = await bot.wait_for(
            "message",
            check=lambda x: x.channel.id == msg.channel.id
            and msg.author.id == x.author.id
            and x.content.lower() == "yes"
            or x.content.lower() == "no",
            timeout=None,
        )

        if res.content.lower() == "yes":
            await sent_message.edit(content=f"{msg.author} said yes!")
        else:
            await sent_message.edit(content=f"{msg.author} said no!")
```

This would result in :
[image: result]

Listening for multiple events is a rather a bit interesting,
Replace the existing `wait_for` with this snippet :

```py
done, pending = await asyncio.wait([
                    bot.loop.create_task(bot.wait_for('message')),
                    bot.loop.create_task(bot.wait_for('reaction_add'))
                ], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

and you can listen for two events simultaneously

Here's how you can handle this using `@bot.command()`

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", case_insensitive=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def response(ctx):
    sent_message = await ctx.channel.send("Waiting for response...")
    res = await bot.wait_for(
        "message",
        check=lambda x: x.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
        and ctx.author.id == x.author.id
        and x.content.lower() == "yes"
        or x.content.lower() == "no",
        timeout=None,
    )

    if res.content.lower() == "yes":
        await sent_message.edit(content=f"{ctx.author} said yes!")
    else:
        await sent_message.edit(content=f"{ctx.author} said no!")


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

[image: new_result]
which would get you the same result.

Comment: I already knew the wait_for command but I did not know how to listen to multiple events simultaneously, so this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!